How to apply a filter only for some domains in postfix
I'd like to know how I can apply a filter for some domains and not for some others.
I tried with access db but the filter is applied to all incoming mails.
It seems that access db isn't taken into account.
Maybe I was not clear enough in my question so here is my config & logs :
mater.cf
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o content_filter=mail2sms:dummy
mail2sms unix - n n - - pipe flags=F user=smmsp:smmsp argv=/pathTo/mail2sms ${user} ${sender}
main.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix-out/access, permit_mynetworks, reject
and access file
@sms.dd.be FILTER mail2sms:dummy
@sms.ee.be FILTER mail2sms:dummy
@smst.dd.be FILTER mail2sms:dummy
@otherdomain.com   permit_mynetworks,reject
LOGS
Dec  4 17:21:20 milou postfix-out/pickup[544417]: 772C010069B1: uid=0 from=
Dec  4 17:21:20 milou postfix-out/cleanup[544953]: 772C010069B1: message-id=20241204162120.772C010069B1@milou.example.com
Dec  4 17:21:20 milou postfix-out/qmgr[544416]: 772C010069B1: from=root@milou.example.com, size=369, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  4 17:21:20 guanlong postfix-out/pipe[544955]: 772C010069B1: to=test@otherdomain.com, relay=mail2sms, delay=0.08, delays=0.01/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via mail2sms service)
Dec  4 17:21:20 milou postfix-out/qmgr[544416]: 772C010069B1: removed
as you can see, filter in also applied to otherdomain.com domain for which I just want to have it treated as normal mail but not passing trought the filter.
Is there a way to do this ?
Thx,
jean-Luc.

Did you build access.db?
How is positionned your postfix server: incoming, outgoing, relay?
Where are the domains you want to filter: yours, external?

I suggest you to make a better description of your functionnal need before exposing configuration files who cannot replace a correct functionnal description.

We can 't trust the From: header in email. Anyone can fake by mail from: x@y.
So filter by header is not a good idea.
https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

You are fully right, but unfortunately this isn't in any way an answer to the OQ.
